# php preg_match & regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to selext url which user posted. So I want to use preg_match.

**String:**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=350000
128/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=750000
500/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1000000
750/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1250000
1000/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1750000
1500/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
```

**My PHP code:**

```
<?php
$quality = $_POST['quality'];
$url = ''.$serviceUrl.'/'.$path.'';
$url = file_get_contents($url);    
preg_match('/'.$quality.'\/prog_index.m3u8/', $url, $C);
print_r($C);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1500/prog_index.m3u8
)
```

But I want like this: **1500/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94**

Comment: Uh... simply add `.+` at the end of your regex? You should really escape this period though `prog_index\.m3u8`.

Comment: You should rather escape (or `(int)` case) the user input; see `preg_quote`. Searching among the lines is much simpler with `file()` and `preg_grep("~^$int/~")` then.

Answer (score 0):

Only based on your provided sample input, add `\S+` which means to pick non-whitespace characters.

```
preg_match('/'.$quality.'\/prog_index.m3u8\S+/', $url, $C);
                                           ^^
```